# How can I align the \angle in matrix elements which is inside a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to align the `\angle`. Any ideas?

```
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        Frequency & S-Parameters $ (\mathrm{dB \ \angle \ deg}) $\\ \hline
         4.2 GHz  & $  \begin{pmatrix}
            -11.04 \ \angle \ 59.12 & -0.44 \ \angle \ -12.20  \\
            -0.44 \ \angle \ -12.20   & -10.15 \ \angle \ 96.15
         \end{pmatrix}  $  \\ \hline
         4.6 GHz  &  $  \begin{pmatrix}
            -13.44 \ \angle \ -29.33 & -0.26 \ \angle \ -36.23  \\
            -0.26 \ \angle \ -36.23   & -13.96\ \angle \ 117.83
         \end{pmatrix}  $ \\ \hline
         5.0 GHz  & $  \begin{pmatrix}
            -10.48 \ \angle \ -89.92 & -0.47 \ \angle \ -58.12  \\
            -0.47 \ \angle \ -58.12   & -10.25 \ \angle \ 156.05
         \end{pmatrix}  $  \\ \hline
         5.4 GHz  &  $  \begin{pmatrix}
            -7.66 \ \angle \ -126.98 & -0.90 \ \angle \ -75.93  \\
            -0.90 \ \angle \ -75.93   & -8.72 \ \angle \ 150.32
         \end{pmatrix}  $ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED to provide 3pt stackgap above and below each `pmatrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\Mangle{\mathbin{\angle}}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            Frequency & S-Parameters $ (\mathrm{dB \angle deg}) $\\ \hline
             4.2 GHz  & $  \addstackgap{\begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
                -11.04 &\Mangle 59.12 & -0.44 &\Mangle -12.20  \\
                -0.44 &\Mangle -12.20   & -10.15 &\Mangle 96.15
             \end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}}  $  \\ \hline
             4.6 GHz  &  $  \addstackgap{\begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
                -13.44 &\Mangle -29.33 & -0.26 &\Mangle -36.23  \\
                -0.26 &\Mangle -36.23   & -13.96&\Mangle 117.83
             \end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}}  $ \\ \hline
             5.0 GHz  & $  \addstackgap{\begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
                -10.48 &\Mangle -89.92 & -0.47 &\Mangle -58.12  \\
                -0.47 &\Mangle -58.12   & -10.25 &\Mangle 156.05
             \end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}}  $  \\ \hline
             5.4 GHz  &  $  \addstackgap{\begin{pmatrix}\begin{aligned}
                -7.66 &\Mangle -126.98 & -0.90 &\Mangle -75.93  \\
                -0.90 &\Mangle -75.93   & -8.72 &\Mangle 150.32
             \end{aligned}\end{pmatrix}}  $ \\ \hline
        \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In this solution, we are aligning \angle within each math function.
What is if, we need to have it inside the math function but need to keep the alignment with other cells as well?

Comment: @Sup I am not sure I understand the follow-up question without the aid of a figure.  However, this follow-up, since it was not included as part of the original question, is probably more appropriate to be asked as a wholly new question on the site.

Comment: I was referring to this question, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352457/how-do-i-align-the-math-symbol-in-each-cell

Comment: @Sup It looks like Werner did a good job answering it.

Answer (score 2):

With use of `array` and `cellspace` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|Sc|}
    \hline
Frequency   & S-Parameters $(\mathrm{dB \angle deg})$\\ 
    \hline
4.2 GHz     & $\left(\begin{array}{r@{\,}l r@{\,}l}
                -11.04 &\angle   59.12 & {-}0.44 &\angle -12.20  \\
                 -0.44 &\angle{-}12.20 & {-}10.15 &\angle  96.15
                      \end{array}\right)$       \\ 
    \hline
4.6 GHz     & $\left(\begin{array}{r@{\,}l r@{\,}l}
                -13.44 &\angle{-}29.33 & {-} 0.26 &\angle -36.23   \\
                -0.26  &\angle{-}36.23 & {-}13.96 &\angle 117.83
                      \end{array}\right)$       \\
    \hline
5.0 GHz     & $\left(\begin{array}{r@{\,}l r@{\,}l}
                -10.48 &\angle{-}89.92 & {-} 0.47 &\angle -58.12   \\
                - 0.47 &\angle{-}58.12 & {-}10.25 &\angle 156.05
                      \end{array}\right)$       \\
    \hline
5.4 GHz     & $\left(\begin{array}{r@{\,}l r@{\,}l}
                -7.66 &\angle{-}126.98  & {-} 0.90 &\angle -75.93  \\
                -0.90 &\angle{-} 75.93  & {-} 8.72 &\angle 150.32
                      \end{array}\right)$       \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** With use of `{-}`, as suggested *egreg* (than you for pointing this) in his comment, the numbers now are visible as negative numbers and not as to be subtracted from `\angle`.

Comment: You should use `{-}` in order not to get binary minus.

Answer (score 2):

You can double the alignment points. I'm also partial to `steinmetz` for this kind of jobs and, of course, of `booktabs`. I recommend `siunitx` for units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,steinmetz,siunitx}

\newenvironment{phasematrix}[1]
 {\left(\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
  \begin{array}{@{} *{#1}{r@{\,}l} @{}}}
 {\end{array}\right)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
Frequency   & S-Parameters (\si{\dB}\phase{\mathrm{deg}}) \\
\midrule
\SI{4.2}{\GHz} &
  $\begin{phasematrix}{2}
  -11.04 & \phase{59.12}  &  -0.44 & \phase{-12.20} \\
   -0.44 & \phase{-12.20} & -10.15 & \phase{96.15}
  \end{phasematrix}$
\\\addlinespace 
\SI{4.6}{\GHz} &
  $\begin{phasematrix}{2}
  -13.44 & \phase{-29.33} & - 0.26 & \phase{-36.23} \\
   -0.26 & \phase{-36.23} & -13.96 & \phase{117.83}
  \end{phasematrix}$
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't like this `\phase` rendering, just remove `steinmetz` and add

```
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{\ensuremath{\angle\mathopen{\,}#1}}
```

[image]

Comment: I know you know how to align these numbers to the dot:)

Comment: @null I don't think it's useful here.