# How do I align the math symbol in each cell?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How do I align `\angle` in each cell, where `\angle` is inside separate inline math mode? Or another solution?

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        Frequency & $ C_{12}  $ $ (\mathrm{dB \ \angle \ deg}) $\\ \hline
        4.2 GHz    &  $ -15.64 \ \angle \ 38.26 $   \\ \hline
        4.6 GHz    &  $ -15.51 \ \angle \ -33.69 $   \\ \hline
        5.0 GHz    &  $ -17.70 \ \angle \ -93.28 $   \\ \hline
        5.4 GHz    &  $ -18.80 \ \angle \ -144.83 $   \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you wish to align the numbers as well? Here are some options:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,eqparbox,collcell}

\newcommand{\setcolentryA}[1]{\eqmakebox[tabcol-\thetable][l]{#1}}
\def\splitanglerange$#1\angle#2${%
  \eqmakebox[tabcol-l-\thetable][r]{$#1$}%
  $\angle$%
  \eqmakebox[tabcol-r-\thetable][r]{$#2$}%
}
\newcommand{\setcolentryB}[1]{%
  \expandafter\splitanglerange#1%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c c }
  \hline
  Frequency & $C_{12}\ (\mathrm{dB \ \angle \ deg})$ \\ 
  \hline
  4.2 GHz   &  $ -15.64 \ \angle \ 38.26 $   \\
  4.6 GHz   &  $ -15.51 \ \angle \ -33.69 $  \\
  5.0 GHz   &  $ -17.70 \ \angle \ -93.28 $  \\
  5.4 GHz   &  $ -18.80 \ \angle \ -144.83 $ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ c<{\ GHz} r @{\ $\angle$\ } r }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Frequency} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$C_{12}\ (\mathrm{dB \ \angle \ deg})$} \\ 
  \hline
  4.2 &  $-15.64$ &   $38.26$ \\
  4.6 &  $-15.51$ &  $-33.69$ \\
  5.0 &  $-17.70$ &  $-93.28$ \\
  5.4 &  $-18.80$ & $-144.83$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ c<{\ GHz} >{\collectcell\setcolentryA}c<{\endcollectcell} }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Frequency} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_{12}\ (\mathrm{dB \ \angle \ deg})$} \\ 
  \hline
  4.2 & $-15.64 \ \angle \ 38.26$   \\
  4.6 & $-15.51 \ \angle \ {-}33.69$  \\
  5.0 & $-17.70 \ \angle \ {-}93.28$  \\
  5.4 & $-18.80 \ \angle \ {-}144.83$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ c<{\ GHz} >{\collectcell\setcolentryB}c<{\endcollectcell} }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{Frequency} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$C_{12}\ (\mathrm{dB \ \angle \ deg})$} \\ 
  \hline
  4.2 & $-15.64 \ \angle \ 38.26$   \\
  4.6 & $-15.51 \ \angle \ -33.69$  \\
  5.0 & $-17.70 \ \angle \ -93.28$  \\
  5.4 & $-18.80 \ \angle \ -144.83$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The first table represent the original setup.

The second table introduces a two-column layout for the "angle column". If you want the right "angle column" to be against the `\angle`, use `l` in the column specification instead of `r`.

The third table uses [`collcell`](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to collect the column entries and insert them into a box which is measured by [`eqparbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)'s `\eqmakebox[<tag>]`. All boxes using the same `<tag>` are set with the same width. `<tag>` here is stepped with every `table` environment and should therefore be unique per `table` (not `tabular`).

The fourth table builds on the third by reverting back to the original two-column `tabular`. A macro extracts the content of the `\angle` column, separating out the lower and upper bounds, and then sets each in their own `\eqmakebox[<l-tag>]`-`\eqmakebox[<r-tag>]` box, thereby ensuring horizontal alignment.

Note that `eqparbox` uses the `.aux` file to store the box content, and therefore requires at least two compilation on the first go (or with any subsequent change in box content).

Comment: Can we do this without having extra columns?

Comment: @Sup: I've added some more options.

Answer (score 3):

You should remove redundant information: if all entries in the first column are measurements in GHz, the unit should be in the header.

Here I show how to get the table in three ways; you may like the final one, where the extra column is masked off in the input by making `\angle` to work like `&`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for the better table
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{An ugly ruled table}

\begin{tabular}{
  |S[table-format=1.1]
  |S[table-format=-2.2]
  @{ $\angle$ }
   S[table-format=-3.2]|
  }
\hline
{Frequency}   & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$C_{12}$} \\
{(\si{\GHz})} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{(\si{\dB} $\angle$ \si{deg})} \\
\hline
4.2 & -15.64 &   38.26 \\ \hline
4.6 & -15.51 &  -33.69 \\ \hline
5.0 & -17.70 &  -93.28 \\ \hline
5.4 & -18.80 & -144.83 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\section{A better table}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  @{ $\angle$ }
   S[table-format=-3.2]
  }
\toprule
{Frequency}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$C_{12}$} \\
{(\si{\GHz})} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\si{\dB} $\angle$ \si{deg})} \\
\midrule
4.2 & -15.64 &   38.26 \\
4.6 & -15.51 &  -33.69 \\
5.0 & -17.70 &  -93.28 \\
5.4 & -18.80 & -144.83 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\section{Perhaps even better}

\begingroup
\let\mathangle=\angle
\let\angle=&
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  @{ $\mathangle$ }
   S[table-format=-3.2]
  }
\toprule
{Frequency}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{$C_{12}$} \\
{(\si{\GHz})} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{(\si{\dB} $\mathangle$ \si{deg})} \\
\midrule
4.2 & -15.64 \angle   38.26 \\
4.6 & -15.51 \angle  -33.69 \\
5.0 & -17.70 \angle  -93.28 \\
5.4 & -18.80 \angle -144.83 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The same trick can be used for the first model (but those rules are really bad, trust me).

[image]

Comment: Great. I'm trying to understand the code here.
can you tell me the use of ,
`\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{siunitx}`
and
`\begingroup
\let\mathangle=\angle
\let\angle=&
\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=-2.2]
  @{ $\mathangle$ }
   S[table-format=-3.2]
  }`

Comment: @Sup `booktabs` is for the better table rules; `siunitx` for units and numeric tables. The trick in the last example is just showing off. `;-)`